# sufficient conditions for faithful group action with multiple orbits

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Suppose group $G$ acts on a set $X$ and has multiple orbits $X_1,\ldots, X_O \subset X$. We know that $G$-action on individual orbits is isomorphic to its action on left-cosets of subgroups $H_1,\ldots, H_O \subset G$. What choice of subgroup $H_1,\ldots, H_O$ makes $G$-action faithful?

For a single orbit $G$-action is faithful when $\bigcap_{g \in G} gHg^{-1} = \{e\}$. Can we get something analogous for multiple orbits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The stabilizer of a point of $X$ is of the form $gH_ig^{-1}$ for certain $g$ and $i$. The action is faithful iff every non-unit element of $G$ does not belong to some stabilizer.

**Answer:**

> ! First you need to prove that the action of $G$ is faithful if and only if the intersection of all stabilizers is the trivial subgroup $\left\{1\right\}$. This should be only a matter of looking at the definitions and rewriting them (e.g. if the action is faithful and $g$ belongs to all stabilizers, then $g\cdot x=x$ for all $x$, so $g$ acts as the identify and thus $g=1$. This is one direction.)
>
> Then verify that any stabilizer of $G$ has the form $gH_og^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$ and some $o$. Putting these two together, the action of $G$ is faithful if and only if $\bigcap_{g\in G}\bigcap_o gH_og{-1}=\left\{1\right\}$.

Comment: is it "iff every non-unit element of G does not belong to SOME stabilizer" or "iff every non-unit element of G does not belong to Any stabilizer across all orbits"?

Comment: @self-educator "to **some** stabilizer". To write it in full, "the action is faithful iff for every $g\neq 1$ there exists $x\in X$ such that $g$ is not in the stabilizer of $x$". If every non-unit element does not belong to any stabilizer, the action is free.

Comment: ah, right,... but how does this translate to a setting with multiple orbits?

Comment: @self-educator This description of faithfulness doesn't care about how many orbits there are.

Comment: I understand. I was looking for a concrete condition (similar what I mentioned for single orbit), that guarantees faithfulness based on the choice of subgroups (stabilizers) $H_1,\ldots, H_O$.

Comment: @self-educator That is precisely what the Hint I gave you should yield. I'll restate the last phrase as "*The action is faithful iff the intersection of all stabilizers is the trivial subgroup $\left\{1\right\}$*". Can you write down a nice expression for "the intersection of all stabilizers", usng the first phrase of the hint?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96657/discussion-between-luiz-cordeiro-and-self-educator).